# Filtering AutoCompleteTextView to show partial match

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Right now I have an AutoCompleteTextView and I want it to work just like the `like "%xxx%"`
does in SQL. I attempted to do it using Filterable I have it and the code runs but it just displays everything now even if there is no partial match. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class CodesArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable{

    List<String> allCodes;
    List<String> originalCodes;

    StringFilter filter;


    public CodesArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> keys) {
        super(context, resource, keys);

        allCodes=keys;
        originalCodes=keys;


    }

    public int getCount() {
        return allCodes.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return allCodes.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class StringFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = originalCodes;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            allCodes = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the complete code of your adapter, you just missed implementing the `getFilter()` method, i.e.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter()
{
    return new StringFilter();
}
```